# Rename duplicate key in pandas series

Tags: pandas

I have the following series. I thought the data was all unique keys, but to my surprise, finviz does use 'EPS next Y' twice. Which causes issues when I go to store it.

What's the correct way to rename the second 'EPS next Y' to 'EPS next Y Perc'?

I was going to just take the series index, find the item number of the duplicate, and rename it that way. Wondering if there is a more 'correct' way.

Thanks

```
EPS (ttm)                   2.33
EPS next Y                  3.13
EPS next Q                  0.64
EPS this Y                63.40%
EPS next Y                24.97%
EPS next 5Y                8.00%
EPS past 5Y               22.30%
```

Comment: Do you get the right result?The example seems wired.The index has to be unique.Are you sure the `EPS` columns is the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Index.duplicated` to find duplicates and add `' Perc'` to those with `pd.Index.str.cat`

```
s.index = s.index.str.cat(np.where(s.index.duplicated(), ' Perc', ''))

s

EPS (ttm)            2.33
EPS next Y           3.13
EPS next Q           0.64
EPS this Y         63.40%
EPS next Y Perc    24.97%
EPS next 5Y         8.00%
EPS past 5Y        22.30%
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
series_index = list(ticker_table.index)
series_index[4] = 'EPS Next Y Perc'
ticker_table.index = series_index
```